# Files can't be accessed after app update/redeployment (ios)

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I story files in the library folder of my (ios-) app:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, requestSuccess);
```

The path to this file is stored in the localStorage.
In case of restarting the app, the files can be found and accessed. The files also can be deleted.

In case of updating/redeploying the app (via xCode or the appStore), the files cannot be accessed, although they exist inside the library folder:

access-error:

[image]

app-container-content:

[image]

The files exist after a redeployment or app-store update, but can't be found/acccessed .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files are accessable after an update by using the cdvfile-path of the cdvfile protocol. 
The file-path has this format:

```
cdvfile://localhost/persistent|temporary|another-fs-root*/path/to/file
```

It can be generated from the file entry this way:

```
fileEntry.toInternalURL()
```

It's important NOT to use the native path of a file like you can get this way:

```
fileEntry.toURL(), //don't use for html-src access
fileEntry.nativeURL //don't use for html-src access
```

This works as html-src too, but no longer if the app was updated or redeployed. The file is still in the filesystem, but can't be accessed by html-src.

I took the examples from this [tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) as referenced in the file-plugin api from the cordova site. But this article seems to be outdated.